# Using cwac-camera via JARs

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the commonsguy cwac-camera library, as per the [demo-layout](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/demo-layout) example, documented in ["Working directlly with cameraview"](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#working-directly-with-cameraview).

All is fine referencing camera/ and camera-v9/ as Android library projects in source form (I need Android 2.3 compatibility, that's what camera-v9 is for).

When I switch to using the library via JARs:
- cwac-camera-v9-0.6.8.jar only includes CameraFragment and BuildConfig classes, so I need also cwac-camera-0.6.8.jar with the other classes.
- including both JARs causes the following self-explaining error when running the project (not at compile time) `Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/BuildConfig;`

I could just use the source as library project, or use Gradle, but I want to know if this is a bug to open an issue on Github, or if I'm doing something wrong.

To replicate the error, just clone the demo-layout example add both .jar files to libs folder, and run the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this appears to be my fault. They must have changed something in the Gradle build process that I am using to create the JARs. I will try to fix this tomorrow. In the meantime, you could go into the `cwac-camera-v9` JAR and try removing the classes in `com.commonsware.cwac.camera`, leaving only those classes in`com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl`.

My apologies for this, and thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @jrub: I have replaced the `camera-v9` JAR for v0.6.8 with one that should not conflict with `camera` on classes in `com.commonsware.cwac.camera`. Grab the updated JAR and let me know if you continue encountering problems with it (either here or by filing an issue).

Comment: they're fine now. Thanks for the nice library!

Comment: @jrub; Glad to hear it fixed your problem. I do need to update my build-a-JAR-from-a-library-project recipe, as the JAR contains `R` and `BuildConfig` stuff that I am not using. My fix was to correct another problem -- I had both `camera` and `camera-v9` using the same package name in the manifest, causing both sets of useless classes to be in the same directory.